# Why does this jQuery fail to load/parse my HTML string?

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, get

```
jQuery.get(window.location.href, function(data) {
  alert(data);
  alert($(data).html());
});
```

The first popup is all the HTML good and healthy.

The second popup is blank. Why? (the HTML is XHTML compliant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#htmlownerDocument):

> The HTML string cannot contain
>   elements that are invalid within a
>   div, such as html, head, body, or
>   title elements.

If you are fetching a complete HTML document, then you will have lots of elements that may not appear in a div.

Answer (score 0):

Because it will return a string with all the HTML. `data` isn't a jQuery object.

Comment: I know this, hence the second attempt tries to turn it into a jQuery object with $(data) !!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my PC. You get back the following:

```
"

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1"><title>

</title><link href="App_Themes/selectors.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head>................etc
```

This will not parse into a jQuery obejct. You get needs to be on a server-side script page that will explicitly output HTML.

I suppose if you really need an item in the HTML then you can strip it out from the text using the built-in string methods.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to something like this

```
$('#yourContainingDiv').html(data);
```

The html in data will be placed in the div tag

Comment: Given the answer from David Dorward, this would fail, as data cannot be placed in a div